# No evidence of code included in a question

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, code-formatting

I've come across a situation where a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14853280/799558) had actually some code along with it, but because the OP didn't add any indentation, I didn't realize it.

There are two reasons why I brought up this topic:

- Many members would think the question has no value and hence downvote (not necessarily this question ) or just leave.
- I've rejected an edit to the question thinking that the editor added code to the question and thought *This edit changes too much in the original post*. and maybe the editor's intention was to post an answer.

Please have a look at the [question revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14853280/revisions). If the question had no grammatical or any sort of mistakes and no one edits the question, would anyone spot the code?

Comment: Switch to the markdown view rather than the rendered output view. Then you'll see that the code had been edited rather than added.

Comment: `I've rejected an edit to the question` That's why you should **always** look at the markdown diff before the post diff.

Comment: Your rejection reason actually reads as "The edit should be an answer to the question". See http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1512596.

Comment: And what exactly is the bug you're reporting? The OP should check what he posts and reviewers should spend some time looking at the markdown diff...I see no bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes you are correct, I wanted to leave a comment but marking it as `This edit changes..` wouldn't let me

Comment: @Bart I wasn't too sure what to include as a tag

Comment: @Bart You missed one. =)

Comment: @AbZy: There is always the 'other' option and adding a custom reason. Not that it applied here.

Comment: thjis is a "bug" at suggester's side; they would better leave comments explaining stuff clearly for reviewer; and no, ["improved formatting"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1512596) doesn't cut it in this case. Something like "fixed markdown mistake of the poster to make their code visible" would do a **much** better job

Comment: @ChrisF Ok I didn't know about the markdown diff. that solves the suggested edits part. how about the first point? if the question wasn't edited at all. how would you evaluate the question?

Comment: I would ask the user to show what they tried, and hopefully they'd reply something along the lines of "I've tried to add my code but it doesn't show", and then that'd be enough of a clue to properly edit the post.

Comment: @J.Steen Oh boy...that is....yeah....*shakes head*

Comment: @J.Steen fair enough. Thank you all for sharing

Comment: One issue is that the markdown+html renderer throws away invalid tags silently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're asking.

1. The solution to the code being hard to spot is to edit it to format the code, as someone did.
2. The solution to you rejecting that edit is to *not do that*. Always look at the Markdown source before deciding on the validity of an edit. Just in the same way that you *always* diff your sources before committing to a version control repository, right?